# Naming: BEGIN ~ END vs LIVE ~ EVIL block structured languages

Tags: shell, sh, language-design, algol68

Curly Bracket languages are well known: ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curly_bracket_programming_language))

Other programming languages can have BEGIN ~ END vs LIVE ~ EVIL block structuring. eg

A) BEGIN ~ END, DO ~ END, IF ~ END IF - examples:
    [Ada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_(programming_language)), [Modula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modula), [Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(programming_language)), [PL/I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/I), [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language))
    etc...

B) IF ~ FI, DO ~ OD, CASE ~ IN ~ OUT ~ ESAC - 
    examples: [Action!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action!), [ALGOL 68](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68), [Bourne 
    shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell), [Cool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool_(programming_language)), [ELLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELLA_(programming_language)), [Guarded Command 
    Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guarded_Command_Language), [Lucid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucid_(programming_language)), [Opal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opal_(programming_language)), [Maple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maple_(software)), [Mary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_(programming_language)), 
    [Polyglot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing)), [Promela](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promela) etc...

What are the official (or-else reasonable) names to differentiate the between the two different styles A) & B) of block structuring ?

Comment: How is this related to best practices or data structures?

Comment: retagged as appropriately as I could imagine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a pun on "reversed" I suggest: IF ~ FI, DO ~ OD, CASE ~ IN ~ OUT ~ ESAC as "reverent" block structuring.

The first case of "reverent" block structuring might be found in [http://ALGOL Bulletin - ISSN: 0084-6198](http://portal.acm.org/browse_dl.cfm?coll=Portal&dl=ACM&idx=J33&linked=1&part=affil), however I cannot find the originators name or an exact posting.

Hence also: BEGIN ~ END, DO ~ END, IF ~ END IF as "irreverent" block structuring.

An example of a technical [palindrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) that appears much earlier (and outside of computing) would be [Lord Kelvin's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Thomson,_1st_Baron_Kelvin) [Mho (℧)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mho#Mho).

Answer (score 3):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curly_bracket_programming_language

FTA:

> Curly brace or bracket programming languages are those which use balanced brackets ({ and }), also known as "squiggly brackets", "brace brackets" or simply "braces") to make blocks in their syntax or formal grammar, mainly due to being C-influenced. The main alternate style is the use of paired keywords, although some languages (notably Python and Occam) instead use an off-side style, and Lisp uses parentheses.

I take from that as meaning:
{} = curly bracket programming languages
BEGIN END = paired keyword
indentation = off-side

Not to say that Wikipedia is definitive, but it seems as close to "official" names as you will get, and most people would probably immediately know what you are talking about if you refer to them as such.

Answer (score 1):

I fear that answer may be dissatisfying. Only names I heard of were **Curly bracket programming languages** and **Non-curly-bracket programming languages** :)

Answer (score 1):

Algol actually started with `if` - `then` - `begin` - `end` syntax before moving to `if` - `then` - `fi` syntax, so it's probably best to avoid calling anything "Algol-like". A lot of people would probably get your drift if you called the `begin` - `end` style "Pascal-like" bracketing, and the `if` - `fi` style "sh-like" bracketing.